# Is it possible to restore data deleted by Adobe Creative Cloud?

Tags: data-recovery

I lost data from the Adobe Creative Cloud bug last week. I have been searching to see if anyone has posted any suggestions other than by a backup source. Can you use any kind of data recovery software on the hard drive that was affected by this bug?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is worth $120 to you, DiskWarrior may help, depending on how long ago you lost data and how much use you've had on the system prior to noticing it (more use = more chance something was overwritten and is now unrecoverable). I realize you asked for no "from backup source" answers, but if Time Machine is enabled, you should have local backups stored on the computer drive, even if you don't have access to your normal backup destination. No external program necessary, just restore the folder.

Comment: Yes. It would be worth it. It happened Thursday morning when I opened my laptop for the day. Have not saved anything to the hard drive. I Have used the computer.

Comment: I contacted DiskWarrior. DiskWarrior can not recover the deleted files.